# Polygon Background Texture in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, image, leaflet, polygon

I am working on a mobile application with leaflet 1.0. The map contains many differently shaped polygons and I want to give them a texture via PNG-Files.

Leaflet's ImageOverlay does pretty much what I want except that it can't clip the image to the shape of the polygon. ImageOverlays only accept imageUrls so I need to have the clipped image locally saved for every individual polygon. Is there a better approach for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

See the "Leaflet.pattern" plugin in the [plugins list](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#markers--renderers).

Comment: The problem with leaflet.pattern is that you can't use images as patterns, only vector layers.

Comment: Oooops, actually I meant the "leaflet-polygon-fillPattern" plugin, a few more lines down.